# How to use gzip encoding with wsgi application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, gzip, wsgi

I'm trying to output gzip encoded strings using wsgi, these are my attempts but unfortunately browser only decodes the first string, any help?

test 1:

```
import zlib

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
    data = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    data += zlib.compress(b'test')[:-4]
    data += zlib.compress(b'test2')[:-4]
    headers.append(('Content-Length', str(len(data))))
    start_response('200 OK',headers)
    return [data]
```

test 2:

```
import zlib

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
    data = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    data += zlib.compress(b'test')
    data += zlib.compress(b'test2')
    headers.append(('Content-Length', str(len(data))))
    start_response('200 OK',headers)
    return [data]
```

test 3:

```
import zlib

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
    start_response('200 OK',headers)
    yield b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    yield zlib.compress(b'test')[:-4]
    yield zlib.compress(b'test2')[:-4]
```

test 4:

```
import zlib

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
    start_response('200 OK',headers)
    yield b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
    yield zlib.compress(b'test')
    yield zlib.compress(b'test2')
```

test 5:

```
import gzip

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
    start_response('200 OK',headers)
    yield gzip.compress(b'test')
    yield gzip.compress(b'test2')
```

Comment: So what is the question - why test1 works and the others don't?

Comment: @mockinterface only the first one decoded in examples above and I got my answer see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the following:

```
 gzip.compress(b'test')
```

return a string with

```
 header  content  THE END
```

in it.

This means when you read it the uncompressing will only return the b'test'. Try it yourself.

Two solutions depending on what you want to achieve:

1. Create a multipart message. Every yield is a new document
2. `compress` does this:

   ```
   def compress(data, compresslevel=9):

       """Compress data in one shot and return the compressed string.
       Optional argument is the compression level, in range of 0-9.
       """
       buf = io.BytesIO()
       with GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb', compresslevel=compresslevel) as f:
           f.write(data)
       return buf.getvalue()
   ```

   Do the something like this:

   ```
   import gzip, io

   def application(environ, start_response):
       headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding',     'gzip')]
       start_response('200 OK',headers)
       buf = io.BytesIO()
       with GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb') as f:
            f.write(b'test')
            f.write(b'test2')
       return buf
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320237/user), and here is my own solution, which I used and I guess we won't buffer a lot of data here:

```
import gzip

class gzipreader:
    def __init__(self):
        self._content = b''

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def write(self,data):
        self._content += data

    def read(self):
        data = self._content
        self._content = b''
        return data

def application(environ, start_response):
    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'),('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')]
    start_response('200 OK',headers)
    reader = gzipreader()
    writer = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb',fileobj=reader)
    for s in [b'test', b'test2']:
        writer.write(s)
        #writer.flush()
        yield reader.read()
    writer.close()
    yield reader.read()
```

Comment: You do not need to implement the reader. You can use `from StringIO import StringIO as gzipreader` under Python2 and `from io import BytesIO as gzipreader` under Python3

Comment: @User it doesn't work the same way, no output for me.

Comment: right, You may not be able to use read there. Just keep that module in mind when you need a file in memory. Sorry.